# How to get specific values from RDD in SPARK with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The following is my RDD, there are 5 fields

```
[('sachin', 200, 10,4,True), ('Raju', 400, 40,4,True), ('Mike', 100, 50,4,False) ]
```

Here I need to fetch 1st ,3rd and 5th Fields only , How to do in PySpark . Expected results as bellow . I tried reduceByKey in several ways, couldn't achieve it

```
Sachin,10,True
Raju,40,True
Mike,50,False
```

Answer (score 2):

With a simple map?

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2], x[4]))
```